# Nginx Masking other domain to my domain

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to mask some other domain to my domain name inside html with nginx, for example :

```
<iframe src="https://example.com/embed/abcd" frameborder="0" width="640" height="450" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

then I want to show to my user like this

```
<iframe src="http://example2.com/embed/abcd" frameborder="0" width="640" height="450" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Is this possible to do with nginx?

I have tried by using nginx `rewrite` and `proxy_pass` but it seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty straightforward using [ngx_http_sub_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter) module of Nginx.

```
sub_filter_types text/html; # optional
sub_filter '//example.com' '//example2.com';
```

It is better to put such statements within `location` block if it is possible for performance reasons.

You may also need to rewrite response headers using [proxy_cookie_domain](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_domain) and [proxy_redirect](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) directives to eliminate more traces of an old domain.

Comment: yes it works but its just replacing the text url so the url gets 404 error

Comment: I have just added more information about `proxy_cookie_domain` and `proxy_redirect` directives to my original answer. It cannot go into more details because it is not clear how you use `proxy_pass` in your Nginx configuration.